# Angular js chunked filter

Tags: angularjs

I am using the following filter:

```
angular.module("chunkFilter", []).
filter('chunked', function () {
    return function (array, chunkSize) {
        if (!(array instanceof Array)) return array;
        if (!chunkSize) return array;

        // Create empty cache if it doesn't already exist.
        if (typeof thisApp.chunkCache === "undefined") {
            thisApp.chunkCache = [];
        }

        // Search the cache to see if we filtered the given array before.
        for (var i = 0; i < thisApp.chunkCache.length; i++) {
            var cache = thisApp.chunkCache[i];
            if (cache.array == array && cache.chunkSize == chunkSize) {
                return cache.result;
            }
        }

        // If not, construct the chunked result.
        var result = chunkArray(array, chunkSize);
        defineHashKeys(result);

        // And then add that result to the cache.
        var cache = {
            array: array,
            chunkSize: chunkSize,
            result: result
        };
        thisApp.chunkCache.push(cache);

        return result;
    };


    function chunkArray(array, chunkSize) {
        var result = [];
        var currentChunk = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            currentChunk.push(array[i]);
            if (currentChunk.length == chunkSize) {
                result.push(currentChunk);
                currentChunk = [];
            }
        }

        if (currentChunk.length > 0) {
            result.push(currentChunk);
        }

        return result;
    }

    function defineHashKeys(array) {
        for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
            array[i].$$hashKey = i;
            console.log(array[i]);
        }
    }


});
```

Taken from another question on StackOverflow (I do not remember which one), this filter knows how to chunk an array into parts (for display in rows).

It's working as expected for the following case :

```
<div class="row-fluid" ng-repeat="offers_chunk in offers | chunked:4">
  <div style="cursor: pointer" class="span3" ng-repeat="offer in offers_chunk" ng-click="selectedOffer(offer)">
     <offer-box></offer-box>
  </div>
</div>
```

with the controller impl:

```
getOffers = ->
    Offer.query().then (offers) ->
      $scope.offers = offers
```

but not working for

```
<div ng-controller="UpcomingCampaignBoxesController">
 <div class="row-fluid" ng-repeat="upcoming_chunk in upcoming_status_boxes | chunked:4">
  <div style="cursor: pointer" class="span3" ng-repeat="campaign in upcoming_chunk">
    <status-box></status-box>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And: 
        root = global ? window

```
UpcomingCampaignBoxesController = ($scope, Campaign, $resource) ->

  getCampaignStatusBoxes = (st)->
    $resource('/campaign/status_boxes', {}).query({status: st})

  $scope.upcoming_status_boxes = getCampaignStatusBoxes("new")

root.UpcomingCampaignBoxesController = UpcomingCampaignBoxesController

RunningCampaignBoxesController = ($scope, Campaign, $resource) ->

  getCampaignStatusBoxes = (st)->
    $resource('/campaign/status_boxes', {}).query({status: st})

  $scope.running_status_boxes = getCampaignStatusBoxes("running")

root.RunningCampaignBoxesController = RunningCampaignBoxesController
```

Without chunking it is working fine. Why is that?

Comment: I do not know, debugging might help.

Comment: what error did you get?